# Convert java encryption to c#

Tags: java, c#

I am struggling to convert the following code to c#:

```
private SecretKey generateSecretKey(char[] key, byte[] salt) {
  this.FACTORY = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
  KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key, salt, 65536, 256);
  SecretKey tmp = this.FACTORY.generateSecret(spec);
  return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
}
```

what is the corresponding algorithm behind PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256/PBEKeySpec in c#?

the java code is then used for something like this:

```
this.secretKey = generateSecretKey(this.key, newSalt);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
c.init(2, this.secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(IV));
```

Also I have noticed that PKCS5PADDING does not exist in C# can it be replaced with PKCS7?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick research and here you go!

> [Seems the 7 & 5 padding algs. are the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615217/9283918)
> [Try using a separate library, such as BouncyCastle.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615216/9283918)
> [Encrypt string with Bouncy Castle AES/CBC/PKCS7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29893607/9283918)

Alright, seems that we could manage to solve part of your problem, but unfortunately Bouncy Castle [doesn't support](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256.

<strike>The last idea that pop up in mind is to use IKVM.net. I know that it's not recommended, but it should work.
Find the sources and recompile it with `PBEWITHHMACSHA256ANDAES_256` provider from e.g. `com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE`.
More about recompiling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65962068/9283918tv).</strike>

In .Net in order to generate PBKDF2 hash you can use [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079370/9283918):

```cs
using (var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
    password,
    saltBytes,
    interactionCount,
    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
{
        derived = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
}
```